# Add microdata per page in html tag angular 5

Tags: angular, microdata

I am working on angular 5 application but i got stuck at one point. I want to add microdata specific to per page dynamically in html tag like

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
```

Is there any way to do that? Please let me know any if any.

Comment: Universal Angular can help you. https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: you could use regular JavaScript to accomplish that from within any component or service. Like:
    `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('itemtype','http://schema.org/QAPage');`

Comment: @igorshmigor, it worked. Thanks, but first I am planning to use somewhat angular specific thing.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina, right now I am not using angular universal as i build it long back but i have upgraded the application to angular 5 recently. Because next month angular 6 going to launch, then i will upgrade again & use universal. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For structured data, google seems to recommend ld+json. Check out [intro to structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data). If you decide to go with ld+json you can use something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'json-ld',
  template: ``,
  styleUrls: ['./json-ld.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class JSONLdComponent implements OnInit {
  private _json: SafeHtml;
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('innerHtml')
  set json(v: any) {
    this._json = this.getSafeHtml(v);
  }

  get json() {
    return this._json;
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  private getSafeHtml(value: object) {
    const json = value
      ? JSON.stringify(value, null, 2).replace(/<\/script>/g, '<\\/script>')
      : '';
    const html = `<script type="application/ld+json">${json}</script>`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

It's available as an [npm package](https://github.com/coryrylan/ngx-libraries/tree/master/src/lib/ngx-json-ld).

If you want to add `<meta>` tags to your page, take a look at the  [Meta](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) class. You can inject it into any component and add/remove/update `meta` tags.

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz Kula, I am giving it a try. Let see then.

Comment: because google recommends to keep structured data in <head> section, I'd refactor code like this:

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private renderer2: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
    let s = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
    s.type = `application/ld+json`;
    s.text = `${JSON.stringify(this.json)}`;

    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.document.head, s);
}

Comment: @MukeshKumar, because it's long back. Yes I have implemented & it was working as well. But as far I remember, I made some changes as well for my requirement.